# Docker container with Flask server stops responding after around 20 requests

Tags: python, docker, flask, tensorflow, flask-restful

I have a docker container that takes in URL to an image, downloads the image to memory using `urllib2`, does some processing to it using Tensorflow, and returns back with JSON data.

The code is structured as follows:

**myapp.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource, inputs
import my_tensorflow
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('url')
class MyApp(Resource):
  def post(self):
    c = my_tensorflow.MyTensorflow(args['url'])
        c.create_graph()
        returned = c.run_inference_on_image()
        return {'results': returned}
api.add_resource(MyApp, '/myapp')
if __name__ == '__main__':
   port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

**my_tensorflow.py**

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import urllib2

class MyTensorflow:

  def __init__(self, url):
     self.imageUrl = imageUrl

  def create_graph(self):
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile("/path/to/model.pb", 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

   def run_inference_on_image(self):
     image_string = urllib2.urlopen(self.imageUrl).read()
     with tf.Session() as sess:
       ...
       ...
       return a_text_value
```

The container works fine for about 20 requests. After about 20 requests it stops responding and just responds with "internal server error". I can't seem to troubleshoot this issue. I put in print statements in my code to see where it becomes unresponsive or errors out but none of the print statements show up in  `docker logs`

`docker logs` doesn't show anything interesting. Below is what it shows:

```
172.17.42.1 - - [13/Feb/2017 21:12:02] "POST /myapp HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

When the container becomes unresponsive (responds with `internal server error`) the `docker stats` returns this:

```
CONTAINER                  CPU %               MEM USAGE/LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O
docker_container   0.01%               2.475 GB/8.255 GB   29.99%              5.328 MB/2.036 MB
```

Everything starts working again once I restart the container with `docker restart`.

I'm not sure what could be going wrong and how I can troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: Maybe `docker events` will show something

Comment: Try running the container in interactive mode (as opposed to running detached and viewing the logs with `docker logs`). Running detached, the output is buffered, and (in my experience anyway) sometimes things are lost, or hang and never print because the buffer doesn't fill enough. When running attached, you do not have that buffering problem.

Comment: Yes, I would also try running from within the container to see if that's a docker networking issues. You can use `--net=host` when running the container to use the host network stack (ie no network namespacing).